# python, selenium, send linebreak to tinymce

Tags: python, selenium, tinymce

I have this code to post in a tinymce textbox:

```
driver.get("http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php")
driver.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('%s')" % "hel\nlo\n\n")
```

It works well when sending a normal string without linebreaks, but when a linebreak is added it throws the exception:

```
    driver.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('%s')" %"hell\no\n\n")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 396, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL\n  (Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.152)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux 3.2.0-60-generic-pae x86)'
```

Which is due to an invalid character. How does one send linebreaks to a tinymce textarea (without using the sendkeys command)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `\n` with  `<br/>` and it should work